# How to parse JSON Date object in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, momentjs

How to parse json date like **/Date(1391802454790-0700)/** to **(01/31/2014 11:44 AM)** in NodeJS.

JSON Date Object:

```
{
    ...,
    "BirthDate":"\/Date(1391802454790-0700)\/",
    ...   
}
```

I tried below code but it doesn't work:

```
var jsondate = "/Date(1391802454790-0700)/";
const data = JSON.parse(jsondate);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let obj = {
  birthday: "/Date(1391802454790-0700)/",
};

let regex = /\(([^)]+)\-\d+/g;

let match = regex.exec(obj.birthday); 
if (match) {
  console.log(match[1]);
  console.log(new Date(Number(match[1])));  // 2014-02-07T19:47:34.790Z - You can use libs to format date
}
```

Comment: You can also take a look at the comment by @tmarwen , it solves your problem much in a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

uhmm, You just gotta use the value of Birthdate and replace the unwanted characters so you can obtain `1391802454790` part; after that you just need to create a valid date out of this  `1391802454790` in the desired format with `new Date()`:

```
 let data = {
        ...,
        "BirthDate":"\/Date(1391802454790-0700)\/",
        ...   
    };
    let birthdate = data.Birthdate;
    birthdate = birthdate.replace("/Date(", "").replace("-0700)/", "");
    let formatedBirthdate = new Date(birthdate);
```

Comment: it works too, I just only add this line: ** let milliseconds = Number(birthdate); ** before this: ** let formatedBirthdate = new Date(milliseconds); **